# How to connect smtp port 25 in second time?

Tags: java, email, tomcat, apache-commons-email

I am using *Apache commons mail* to send mail in my web application. My web application is hosted in Tomcat. When I try to send mail for the first time after server starts. I am able to send mail. But after that, when I attempted second time, it is not connecting to SMTP `port 25`.

By using `setDebug(true);`, I could able to find that after `emailObj.send()`, it closes the connection. So then it couldn't connect next time.

How to resolve my issue?

Comment: Whats the error message?

Comment: Could not connect to SMTP port <servername> port 25, response -1

Answer (score 1):

Are you reusing the same Email instance ?

Email is a class representing one Email, which you will sent through send() method.

If you want to send another email, you have to instantiate a new Email object.

Comment: No. I am creating HtmlEmail object locally inside the method. So for every invocation, it should be creating new one. So i am not reusing the same instance.

Comment: Sorry. Actually for some other purpose, i have set proxy settings. That blocked the port. It is working fine.Thanks for your responses